# VBA Script hard code email address

Tags: email, vba

(update) - The way this script currently runs is when you are in an active email folder (...@**.com/inbox) or (...@**.com/deleted), it runs the script on that email folder.  So it outlook automatically knows which email if selected.  I want it to do thisemail@thisplace.com always.   And this is being run through Outlook's VBA

So I have this neat VBA script that exports my inbox folder from a selected email address in outlook to Microsoft Excel.  The thing I would like is to automate this even further so that the email address is hard coded into the script.  Basically I don't want to have to select an email address to run the script, I just want the script to run on one specific email address always.  Here is my code:

```
Sub Extract()


On Error Resume Next
Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application
Set myfolder = myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder


Set xlobj = CreateObject("excel.application.14")
Set xlobjWbk = xlobj.Workbooks.Open("c:\Users\(my username)\Desktop\Example.xlsx")
xlobj.Visible = True
xlobj.EnableEvents = True

'Set Heading
xlobj.Range("a" & 1).Value = "Recieved Time"
xlobj.Range("b" & 1).Value = "Sender Email"
xlobj.Range("c" & 1).Value = "Subject"
xlobj.Range("d" & 1).Value = "Sender Name"
xlobj.Range("e" & 1).Value = "Body"

For i = 1 To myfolder.Items.Count
 Set myItem = myfolder.Items(i)
 msgtext = myItem.body

 xlobj.Range("a" & i + 1).Value = myItem.ReceivedTime
 xlobj.Range("b" & i + 1).Value = myItem.SenderEmailAddress
 xlobj.Range("C" & i + 1).Value = myItem.Subject
 xlobj.Range("d" & i + 1).Value = myItem.SenderName
 xlobj.Range("e" & i + 1).Value = msgtext

 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I am not 100% familiar with VBA, but where does your method ask for an email address? You could traverse your accounts and pick the one with the appropriate email, then dig into that account's inbox?

Comment: Are you looking for a Excel-VBA Code or Outlook-VBA Code?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i can see from you example i take it that you run your routine against your active outlook instance and selected folder (myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder).

Outlookfolders have id attributes. You could use that to meet your goal.
You can get it with -> ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.EntryID.
Then use it by -> Set targetFolder = GetNamespace("MAPI").GetFolderFromID(folderID)

Comment: It appears that the EntryID changes slightly on an undefined basis... is there any way to get this ID stationary so that whenever I run the script it can always run it on the right email address?